# Configuring autogrow plugin with djangocms-text-ckeditor

Tags: django-cms, django-ckeditor

I am trying to use the autogrow plugin for ckeditor.  As I am new to django and ckeditor I am having trouble with configuration.  My settings are not being recognized.  Below is a list of steps.  I have seen reference to having to build ckeditor over again. I do not know if this is needed.

Platform: Ubuntu, django-cms 3 beta, djangocms-text-ckeditor (installed used pip in virtualenv), python 2.7.

I do not know exactly what I need to do, but I changed the following anyway.

S1. In project's settings.py, added

> ```
> CKEDITOR_SETTINGS = getattr(settings, 'CKEDITOR_SETTINGS', { 
>    'config.autoGrow_onStartup': True,
>     'config.autoGrow_minHeight': 200,
>     'config.autoGrow_maxHeight': 400,
>  })
> ```

S2. In ../site-packages/django_text_ckeditor/static/ckeditor/config.js, edited

> ```
> CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
> // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
> // config.language = 'fr';
> // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
>     config.autoGrow_onStartup = true;
>     config.autoGrow_minHeight =  2000;
>     config.autoGrow_maxHeight = 4000;
> };
> ```

S3. Added the autogrow plugin folder to

> "../site-packages/django_text_ckeditor/static/ckeditor/plugins/autogrow"

S4. Modified line 45 of

> ```
> "../site-packages/django_text_ckeditor/static/js/cms.ckeditor.js"
> ```
>
> 'extraPlugins': 'cmsplugins, autogrow'

S5. Added an extra statement after line 58 of

> "../site-packages/django_text_ckeditor/static/js/cms.ckeditor.js"
>
> ```
> //  this is line 58 
> CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('cmsplugins', settings.static_url + 'ckeditor_plugins/cmsplugins/'); 
> //  this is the added line
> CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('autogrow', settings.static_url + 'ckeditor/plugins/autogrow');
> ```

Do not know what else to do?  Thoughts?  Advice?

Answer (score 1):

I'am using standard django-ckeditor from here: https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor

Your Step S2 and S4 and S5 are not needed. It makes no sens to modify the source of ckeditor. Just download the autogrow plugin from http://ckeditor.com/addon/autogrow and config with settings.py:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'autoGrow_onStartup': True,
        'autoGrow_minHeight': 100,
        'autoGrow_maxHeight': 650,
        'extraPlugins': 'autogrow',
            'toolbar': 'Custom',
            'toolbar_Custom': [
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'],
            ['Format'],
            #['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
            ['Link', 'Unlink'],
            ['RemoveFormat', 'Source']
        ],
    }
}
```